# How to stream live video for multiple users?

Tags: http-live-streaming, live-streaming, clappr

I am building a new website with a Wordpress theme, I have Clappr video frame embedded in my website for streaming live videos.
I am using m3u8 link within Clappr player and it works fine when a user browse my website and start watching. But when another user access to the website and start watching, the streaming immediately disconnects with the first user.

I have tried a lot of Media players, but all have problems with the browsers, like some of them were not working on all platforms.

This is the code where I implement the Clappr player in my html page:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
 var player = new Clappr.Player({source: "streamingsourcehere.m3u8", parentId: "#player",autoPlay: true, playback: { playInline: true, recycleVideo: Clappr.Browser.isMobile }});

</script>
```

I expect that any user can access my website and start watching, it works fine with the first user, but when another user access my website the streaming disconnect with the first user.
Note: I get 403 (Forbidden) with the first user when another user access to the website.

Comment: This will have nothing to do with your player... the problem is going to be server-side.  Also, if you're expecting any HLS player to work on "all browsers", don't.  It's only going to work for browsers that support MSE, or browsers that support HLS natively.

Comment: @Brad Yes It's a server-side problem, but I have tried a lot to figure out what's wrong but I couldn't. Is there any solution for this ? And do you recommend a better  way to work on all browsers ?

Comment: If you know it's a server-side problem, why are you showing us your client-side code?  You didn't even mention what server you're using.  You didn't show us any network traces or anything that might indicate what's going on.  At least open your developer tools and figure out if you're getting error status codes or something.

Comment: Just edited it, and I didn't know it before that it's a server side problem, just wondering if there is a specific idea to search for, and if there is a better player or even a better way to support all browsers. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use a media server to generate a link that can be accessed from an 
and it worked!